# Can INF files be used as installer programs?

Tags: windows, installation, inf

Can INF files be used as installer programs? While INFs are mostly used for drivers, they can be used to create registry keys and copy files to certain locations. It would make sense that they can also be used as installers? Is there anything preventing people from using them as such?
Lastly, .cat Catalog files can be used to code sign such installations.

Comment: Use manufacturer's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/using-a-universal-inf-file).